# Uploading a text/word file into cakephp and then view it in realtime

Tags: debugging, cakephp

I want to be able to upload files into database and then have a link for view so that I can see this file as well. Basically all saved files should show up in index page and if I click a view button the content of  file should show up in view page. I am using these codes, here's my controller part :

```
    public function add(){

        if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Doc->create();
        $filename = $this->request->data['Doc']['docname']['name'];
        $this->request->data['Doc']['docname'] = $filename;

        if ($this->Doc->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Message : ' . $filename);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));


        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Doc could not be saved. Please, try again'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my add function in under app/view :

```
  <div class="doc form">
       <?php echo $this->Form->create('Doc', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
<table align="left">
<tr>
    <td>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('docname', array('type' => 'file'));?>
    </td>


</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
        <div align="center" style="padding: 20px">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link('Cancel',array('controller' =>         'docs', 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->button('Submit',array('type'=>'upload','class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

All I get is only the name of the file get saved in database and all this names shows up in my index page as well, but if I click view I just see the names of the file not the content under it. I am new in cake-php so I doubt if this is the correct approach or not.
I am using Cake-Php 2.4 version. Database is postgres. My table is like this:

Column           Type
id           (integer)
docname       (character varying(255))
grant_id        (integer(fk))

And my Doc model looks like this

```
      class Doc extends AppModel {


//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are    not needed can be removed


public $belongsTo = array(
    'Grant' => array(
        'className' => 'Grant',
        'foreignKey' => 'grant_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Could you tell the version of cakephp used, show the table/db used and show the model of Doc?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have just edited my question and put the details you asked.

Comment: This plugin maybe will help you: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload